# Unable to fetch Education details in linkedin Rest API

Tags: java, json, linkedin-api

I am fetching data from given url in JSON format

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,headline,formatted-name,picture-url,siteStandardProfileRequest,educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes),positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)))?format=json

Everything works fine, But I am not getting response for education.

Sample Response -

```
{
    "firstName": "FNAME",
    "lastName": "LNNAME",
    "emailAddress": "S*******@gmail.com",
    "formattedName": "FNAME LNNAME",
    "pictureUrl": "https:\/\/media.licdn.com\/mpr\/mprx\/0****",
    "positions": {
        "_total": 1,
        "values": [{
                "summary": "J2EE DEVELOPER",
                **
                **
            }
        }]
}, "id": "5cNYNt0sTY", "headline": "*** Consultancy", "siteStandardProfileRequest": {
    "url": "https:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/profile\/view?id=********"
}
```

Comment: This feels like a question for linked in support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Education data is not part of the set of basic profile fields that you have access to.  The complete list is available here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

Comment: Yes saw that, And there is no way to get complete data without being partner with them.

Comment: then how can i access education details?